# Como buscar e atualizar dados com o mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Estou utilizando o mongodb com o mongoose no nodejs, tenho meu schema assim:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        require: true
    },
    balances: {
        dolar: {
            manualBalance: {
                type: Number,
                select: false
            },
            paidBalance: {
                type: Number,
                select: false
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Tento então fazer isso:

```
router.post('/get_user_balance', async (req, res) => {
    const { username } = req.body;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username }, { $set: { balances: {dolar: {manualBalance: '1.50' }}}});
        const balances = await User.findOne({ username }).select('+balances.dolar.manualBalance');
        console.log(balances);
}
```

e recebo do nodejs o erro:

```
(node:22826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.
```

Acredito que seja `.select('+balances.dolar.manualBalance');` que esteja errado. Assim também tentei sem o select e retirei o "select: false" do meu schema, retesei o banco e criei novamente um usuário, e recebo do console.log apenas o username, ao invés de também receber o campo "balances".

```
{
  _id: 5ab00b7a92fe402bb85f407f,
  username: 'Jerildo',
  __v: 0
}
```

Estou registrando os usuários assim:

```
const user = await User.create(req.body);
```

onde req.body é : `{username: "jerildo"}`

Sei que deve ser coisa simples que estou errando por não conhecer tão bem o mongodb ou o mongoose, sempre trabalhei com Redis, isso aqui é novo para mim. Então peço uma força aqui.

Comment: Em produção não use a entrada do usuário diretamente para o banco... sanitize, escape strings e se possível (e altamente recomendado) desative a execução de javascript no banco. No arquivo de configuração defina: security -> javascriptEnabled: false

Comment: @LauroMoraes agradeço as informações, mas não está em produção, ainda não olhei para a segurança, mais para frente irei estudar sobre segurança em relação ao mongodb. Preciso primeiramente aprender a utilizar ele, e como pode ver na questão, não estou sabendo XD

Comment: Eu não sei por que você esta usando `async`...poderia simplesmente encadear. Usando `async` "não encadeado" deve esperar (await) na primeira (findOneAndUpdate) e na segunda (findOne) requisição. Deves passar o argumento `new: true` em `findOneAndUpdate()` caso queira retornar o documento modificado. Eu vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Estou utilizando async pois minha API utiliza async. findOneAndUpdate() apenas retorna um documento. Mas ignoremos o findOneAndUpdate(), apenas o outro findOnde(), ele não deveria me retornar {username: "jerildo", Balances:{dolar: {manualBalance: 0}}} ? porque me retorna apenas o username?

Comment: Estou editando a minha resposta com um exemplo que testei localmente... esta me retornando tanto o usuário quanto o balanço. Termino logo

Comment: Você poderia me recomendar algum módulo para lidar com o "escape strings"? Sanitize pelo que vi é apenas rejeitar caso `(/^\$/.test(mystring))` seja **true** , assim o usuário não poderá injetar utilizando **$ne** por exemplo, certo?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mongo-sanitize

Comment: Foi exatamente esse módulo que vi, apenas faz essa verificação (/^\$/.test(mystring)) mesmo kkkkk e para lidar com o "escape strings"?

Comment: Este módulo não verifica somente, ele aceita opões e pode excluir entradas "de injeção" ou mesmo substituir entradas "maliciosas" pre definidas. Veja o código fonte no GitHub: https://github.com/fiznool/express-mongo-sanitize/blob/master/index.js . Más a melhor prevenção contra injeção NoSQL em MongoDB é (e continua sendo) desabilitar o JavaScript no banco

Comment: confundi com o mongo-sanitize, vou dar uma lida nele aqui.

Comment: @LauroMoraes li aqui https://zanon.io/posts/nosql-injection-in-mongodb que o mongoose não precisa sanitizar, ele já converte para string quando você especifica o type: String. Assim evitando a injeção.

Comment: Pode confirmar aqui também http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html sobre o mongoose converter para string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários:

> eu não sei por que você esta usando `async`...

Pois bem ao utilizar `async` deve esperar (await) tanto na primeira requisição (findOneAndUpdate()) quanto na segunda (findOne()) o que por sinal já esta fazendo.

Por padrão a função `findOneAndUpdate()` retorna o documento original, se queres retornar o documento modificado deves passar um argumento no objeto de opções exemplo:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({}, {}, {new: true})
```

Imaginando que tenha criado um documento, então o seguinte exemplo:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    username: 'Jerildo'
}, {
    $set: {
        balances: {
            dolar: {
                manualBalance: '1.50'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    new: true // retorna o novo objeto
})

const balances = await User.findOne({ username: 'Jerildo' }).select('+balances.dolar.manualBalance')
console.log(balances)
```

Irá retornar o documento modificado (no console.log())

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opcionalmente você pode encadear a resposta (resultado) de `findOneAndUpdate()` lgo como:

```
await USER.findOneAndUpdate({
    username: 'Jerildo'
}, {
    $set: {
        balances: {
            dolar: {
                manualBalance: '1.50'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    new: true // retorna o novo objeto
}, (err, doc) => {
    if ( err ) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    // o documento com o novo valor (atulizado)
    console.log(doc)
})
```

---

NOTA: eu define o `username` para este exemplo, você deve verificar (validar) seu esquema de requisição para garantir que haja um `username`.

Comment: Mas na questão mesmo digo que também testei sem o "select: false". Leia ela com mais atenção novamente.

Comment: Sim, desatenção minha. Tente com `.exec()` e diga o que retorna

Comment: Tentei com ".exec()" e recebo o mesmo erro: `name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.',`

Comment: ainda recebo o mesmo erro com o seu exemplo.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar retornando **User.findOneAndUpdate** para a **const balances**, já que o outro findOne estava sendo desnecessário. Mas há algo errado com essa linha `const balances = await User.findOne({ username: 'Jerildo' }).select('+balances.dolar.manualBalance')` e algo me diz q é no "+balances.dolar.manualBalance", como está seu schema?

Comment: Hum... só posso imaginar que você tenha um trecho de código "conflitando". Este é meu Gist contendo exatamente o exemplo que postei aqui, o único diferencial é o schema, modelo e configuração de conexão (local). Teste e diga se funcinona? https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/6b130422b7b306bd6586d77c7b365056

Comment: Opa, erro meu, eu tinha esquecido de novamente adicionar a linha "select: false" no meu schema.